# How to split a table in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table

```
id  name    attribute1  attribute2  attribute3
1   mike    red            white       red
2   hike    black          red         black
3   nike    green          green       blue
```

I want to apply ALL attributes to each `id and name` rows like this

```
id  name    attribute1  attribute2  attribute3
1   mike    red            white       red
1   mike    black          red         black
1   mike    green          green       blue
2   hike    red            white       red
2   hike    black          red         black
2   hike    green          green       blue
3   nike    red            white       red
3   nike    black          red         black
3   nike    green          green       blue
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have tried to do this using `CSVReader` API on Java. It worked but I am required to do it in Excel. I have no clue how to start

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select your two ranges separately (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>): first range with id & name, second range with attributes (not including titles for either, then run the attached code:

```
Sub JoinAndExpand_MultiColumnRange1()
Dim rg1 As range, rg2 As range, shtDest As Worksheet, rgCell As range
Dim lLoop As Long, lRowDest As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

If selection.Areas.Count <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "Select two areas to join"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rg1 = selection.Areas(1)
Set rg2 = selection.Areas(2)
Set shtDest = Worksheets.Add

lRowDest = 1

For lLoop = 1 To rg1.Rows.Count
    shtDest.Cells(lRowDest, 1).Resize(rg2.Rows.Count, rg1.Columns.Count).Value = rg1.Rows(lLoop).Value
    rg2.Copy shtDest.Cells(lRowDest, 1 + rg1.Columns.Count)
    lRowDest = lRowDest + rg2.Rows.Count
Next

With application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're just lucky I've had that issue before ;)

Comment: And that gave me a blog post: http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/simulate-an-outer-join-with-excel/